# cant access manager app in tomcat while i have configure the tomcat-user.xml file

Tags: tomcat

**tomcat-user.xml file**
Is there any other file which has to configured

```
 <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd">

         <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="abcd" password="abcd" roles="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="abcd" password="abcd" roles="manager-script"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Does your XML file pass an XML validator? Try `xmllint`. Is the file in the right place? Where is it? Is the `<Realm>` configured anywhere? Where?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a version 8 or higher of Tomcat (I'm not sure in versions 7), you should also modify the following file:

**/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml**

(I'm assuming you have Tomcat installed in the "/opt/tomcat" directory).

Inside, comment out the IP address restriction to allow connections from anywhere. Alternatively, if you would like to allow access only to connections coming from your own IP address, you can add your public IP address to the list:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" /> -->
</Context>
```

More info [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Regards.